# Java Agent Class Loader

Tags: java, instrumentation, javaagents

I have a problem with how to instruct class loader to use Java Agent jar as a reference for classes.
I am using VirtualMachine to attach to specified process with Java Agent, and with most of
the cases it works. But in the case of attaching the complex app(e.g. Wildfly) which uses own
class loaders, class loader cannot find classes.

This is a short version of java agent:

```
package mypackage;
public class JavaInstrumentAgent 
{
    public JavaInstrumentAgent()
    {
    }

    public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation instr) {
        instrument(args, instr);
    }

    public static void agentmain(String args, Instrumentation instr) {
        instrument(args, instr);
    }

    private static void instrument(String args, Instrumentation instr) {
        instr.addTransformer(new JavaInstrumentTransformer(), true);
    }
}
```

a transformer:

```
package mypackage;
public class JavaInstrumentTransformer implements ClassFileTransformer
{
    public JavaInstrumentTransformer()
    {
        CtClass.debugDump = "F:\\tmp\\ct";
    }

    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
        byte[] byteCode = null; 
        String cn = className.replaceAll("/", "\\.");
        try {
            ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();
            classPool.importPackage("mypackage.AgentManager");
            classPool.insertClassPath(new LoaderClassPath(loader));
            CtClass ctClass = classPool.makeClass(new ByteArrayInputStream(classfileBuffer));
            CtMethod[] methods = ctClass.getDeclaredMethods();
            for (CtMethod method : methods) {
                if (Modifier.isNative( method.getModifiers())) continue ;
                    String params = "\"" + cn + "\",\"" + method.getName() + "\"";
                    method.insertBefore("mypackage.AgentManager.start(" + params + ");");
                
            }
            byteCode = ctClass.toBytecode();
            ctClass.detach();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return byteCode;
    }
}
```

and a call collector:

```
package mypackage;
public class AgentManager 
{
    private AgentManager() {
    }

    public static void start(String clazz, String methodName)
    {
        System.out.println(clazz + ":" + methodName);
    }
}
```

If I attach to a simple application, like this:

```
public class Test()
{
    public void test()
    {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Test().test();
    }
}
```

I can see in Javassist dump, that transformation is done well and looks like:

```
import mypackage.AgentManager ;

public class Test()
{
    public void test()
    {
        mypackage.AgentManager.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Test().test();
    }
}
```

and I can see runing test method,
but that's because a transformer uses default class loader, which loaded
also mypacket.AgentManager class.
If I try to attach to a Wildfly process to monitor my web services on it,
I got transformer compile error:

(Test) Exception in thread "Test" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mypackage/AgentManager

I tried:

```
classPool.appendClassPath("MyAgent.jar");
intrumentation.appendToSystemClassLoaderSearch("MyAgent.jar");
instrumentation.appendToBootstrapClassLoaderSearch("MyAgent.jar");
```

but nothing changes. Any help/hint how I could notify attached process
class loader to look also in MyAgent.jar would be appreciated.

Comment: `appendToBootstrapClassLoaderSearch` should be sufficient for any class loaders following the parent delegation model. For class loaders doing their own thing, there is no general solution.

Comment: I thought too, but it doesnt work (Verify error). What I found out that there are some bugs in specific java versions, when bootstrap loader at runtime acts strange with a normally compiled code. Will try to update to see if its any better.